# Can't display all upsell products in magento, 1 product is missing

Tags: magento, product

I don't understand why upsell doesn't show 1 product in the frontend. All upsell products are showing up except for 1. I've reindexed all data, but still no changes. All upsell products are in stock, they all have quantity and they are all enabled, but still 1 product doesn't show up in the frontend. I've tried to check only 1 product, which is the product that is missing but didn't show up, any help, please. Thanks.
By the way, it is not modified in the catalog.XML so the product limit is not the issue.

here is the backend
http://ecommerceoutsourcing.co/projects/UMD/magento/skin/frontend/default/theme542/images/upsell_products_backend.png

and here is the frontend
http://ecommerceoutsourcing.co/projects/UMD/magento/skin/frontend/default/theme542/images/upsell_products_frontend.png

Comment: Is this question about programming?

Comment: no, all is set in the backend of Magento, I can display all upsell products in the frontend except for 1, you can check out the link that I gave, thanks. As you can see on the link, the checked products in the backend are product a and product b, but Product  A is the only one that is displayed in the frontend.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. SO is a programming Q & A site. I suggest you post this on http://magento.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'm a newbie sorry